# Chromebook does not show the app page

Tags: chromebook

A friend has two google accounts and one chromebook. Neither google account will display the app page on the chromebook. Prolly not helpful, but included is a screen capture of the message.

[screen capture showing the "Page Not Displayed" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpqDr.png)

Logging into any other computer using either of his two google accounts does properly display the app page. Logging out and in on the chromebook doesn't change things. Clearing the cache on the chromebook doesn't help.

I've asked him to check his proxy settings, and to have a friend try yet a different google account.

He's stumped, I'm stumped--are you? What would block the app page on a chromebook straight out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

The "search" button should bring it up. It is the button located where other keyboard have Caps Lock. The function of pressing that key can be assigned in `chrome://settings` in the keyboard area. A list of special pages is at `chrome://about`

Oddly the apps don't have that `chrome://apps` anymore. It seems to be removed in later versions of chrome. The apps are shown in "app launcher." The tray across the bottom is called the "shelf". I did some searching but did not find any more workarounds using those key words but did read some interesting pages.